# Printing symbol table like entries during kernel bootup in ARM

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, armv7

Is there any way that we can write a function to print symbol table like entries i.e.,`c03441a0 t dmi_broken` during kernel boot time for debugging purposes for ARM architecture. This is required during early bootup.

Comment: [`dump_stack()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/lib/lockdep/uinclude/linux/stacktrace.h) and [CONFIG_STACKTRACE](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/stacktrace.c) might be helpful.  These will increase the size of your binary.  I am pretty sure they work fine even during early bootup (depending on your meaning of 'early'; obviously nothing works on the first instruction or before stack is set up, etc).  [`sprintf_symbol`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/kallsyms.h) seems to do what you want, but depends on **CONFIG_KALLSYMS**.

Comment: @artlessnoise Can you please point as to where the stack is set up in the kernel source code?

Comment: It is initially done in [head.S](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S), but there are different stacks in use.  I mean you need different ways to debug head.S.

Comment: @artlessnoise Can I take the symbol table that kallsyms use from the kernel image during early boot of kernel through some function and print the symbol name for debugging. I need to do this because I heard that symbol names are generated after the kernel bootup and I want it during bootup for debugging errors.

Comment: @igorskochinsky I have seen your post on linux kernel symbols for arm.Can you point me somewhere on how can this be done.

Comment: The fixups are done in head.S (ARM assembler which has it's own debug), so if you don't want to debug that and just 'C' code then you can use `sprintf_symbol` anywhere.  Also, with kernel hacking and **CONFIG_DEBUG_LL**, you can use `printascii()` and shove it in `vprintk_emit` as detailed in other places.

Comment: @artlessnoise How can I use `sprint_symbol` in `start_kernel` function. I have tried like `char sym[KSYM_SYMBOL_LEN]; sprint_symbol(sym,(unsigned long)tick_init);` after `tick_init` function call. It does not work.